# Do you earn XP in co-op/zombies modes?

Tags: call-of-duty-world-at-war, cod-world-at-war-zombies

After a long match of Zombies I get no progress - no XP, no completed challenges - nothing.

Does only the competitive multiplayer award experience (XP)?

[image: After Action Report - 0 XP]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, anything co-op does not increase your online exp